# NamedPipes in Windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-7, named-pipes

I am trying to create a named pipe. The server will create the pipe and writes data into it and the client connect to that pipe and read the data. It works for me when i gave the name for pipe as the default name

```
\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe
```

But when i try to give my machine it is not working..

```
\\\\MyMachine01\\pipe\\mynamedpipe
```

Is this allowed? Right now both my client and server programmes are in the local machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Pipe Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365783(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation:

> The pipe server cannot create a pipe on another computer, so CreateNamedPipe must use a period for the server name, as shown in the following example.
>
> ```
> \\.\pipe\PipeName
> ```

You should be able to use a qualified name for the "clients" though.

Comment: it is using the same machine. Name of local machine is MyMachine.
Is that possilbe?

Comment: Please read that quote attentively: "CreateNamedPipe **must** use a period for the server name".